# Python - How to remove a sentence if it contains spanish words

Tags: python, text, nltk

As the title states, I've got a dataset that includes strings that are either english or spanish. Prior to preprocessing, I want to remove any row that includes Spanish words.

Should I just use a spanish corpus loop through the entire dataset to see of any spanish words exist in the sentence?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you implement your idea?  What doesn't work about it?  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet. Actually having trouble gathering the spanish word corpus

Comment: ... which leaves you asking for speculative design advice -- beyond the purpose of Stack Overflow.  Your straightforward approach is an "obvious" workable solution.  Sort your corpus by expected frequency to promote early detection.

Comment: What if your text had one Spanish word? Perhaps you need to work on an English/Spanish ratio metric. See [Detecting text language](http://blog.alejandronolla.com/2013/05/15/detecting-text-language-with-python-and-nltk/)

Comment: Take a look at [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/). I've never tried it myself but heard good stuff about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the library you'll want to use is [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/). Here's some example code I just whipped up + output.

```
from langdetect import detect

sentences = ["hello, how are you",
             "Hola cómo estás",
             "I've had a great day"]

for sentence in sentences:
    print(detect(sentence)) # outputs 'en', 'es', 'en'
```

Hope this helps, happy to answer any follow up questions

Comment: This works, thanks! Its quite computationally expensive but it seems like the only option I have been able to find.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I think this will be way simpler than trying to write anything yourself.